# NSManagedObjectDidSaveNotification not working

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, core-data

I'm writing a simple core data OS X app, and I have faced a problem with multithreaded core data. The problem is that I want to change a boolean value in a background thread, but when I save, the value returns to the old value. I also change a string value in the same thread, and it works perfectly.

Here's my code (little simplified)

```
@implementation UpdateOperation
...
- (void)main {
    @try {
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [context setPersistentStoreCoordinator:[delegate persistentStoreCoordinator]];

        // Register context with the notification center
        NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]; 
        [nc addObserver:self
               selector:@selector(mergeChanges:)
                   name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                 object:context];

        NSArrayController *siteArrayController = [[NSArrayController alloc] init];
        [siteArrayController setManagedObjectContext:context];
        [siteArrayController setEntityName:@"Page"];
        [siteArrayController fetchWithRequest:nil merge:YES error:NULL];

        ...

        [[[siteArrayController arrangedObjects] objectAtIndex:0] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"updated"];
        [[[siteArrayController arrangedObjects] objectAtIndex:0] setValue:newMD5 forKey:@"oldMD5"];

        NSLog(@"[context updatedObjects] before saving: %@", [context updatedObjects]);
        NSLog(@"Object 0 before saving: %@", [[siteArrayController arrangedObjects] objectAtIndex:0]);

        NSError *error;
        BOOL saveSucceeded = [context save:&error];
        NSLog(@"saveSucceeded: %@", (saveSucceeded ? @"YES" : @"NO"));
        NSLog(@"error: %@", error);

        NSLog(@"Object 0 after saving: %@", [[siteArrayController arrangedObjects] objectAtIndex:0]);

    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {

    }
}

- (void)mergeChanges:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *mainContext = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    NSLog(@"Notification updated objects: %@", [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:NSUpdatedObjectsKey]);
    // Merge changes into the main context on the main thread
    [mainContext performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:)
                                  withObject:notification
                               waitUntilDone:YES];  
}

@end
```

Output looks like this:

```
[context updatedObjects] before saving: {(
    <NSManagedObject: 0x2000aacc0> (entity: Page; id: 0x200025ce0 <x-coredata://77B4A16E-0BE3-4D2F-8026-C11CBC35C609/Page/p102> ; data: {
    address = "http://stackoverflow.com";
    name = Stackoverflow;
    oldMD5 = cd32dbfb6fc3f7cca09f45ee811cab0;
    updated = 1;
})
)}

Object 0 before saving: <NSManagedObject: 0x2000aacc0> (entity: Page; id: 0x200025ce0 <x-coredata://77B4A16E-0BE3-4D2F-8026-C11CBC35C609/Page/p102> ; data: {
    address = "http://stackoverflow.com";
    name = Stackoverflow;
    oldMD5 = cd32dbfb6fc3f7cca09f45ee811cab0;
    updated = 1;
})

Notification updated objects: {(
    <NSManagedObject: 0x2000aacc0> (entity: Page; id: 0x200025ce0 <x-coredata://77B4A16E-0BE3-4D2F-8026-C11CBC35C609/Page/p102> ; data: {
    address = "http://stackoverflow.com";
    name = Stackoverflow;
    oldMD5 = cd32dbfb6fc3f7cca09f45ee811cab0;
    updated = 0;
})
)}

saveSucceeded: YES
error: (null)  

Object 0 after saving: <NSManagedObject: 0x2000aacc0> (entity: Page; id: 0x200025ce0 <x-coredata://77B4A16E-0BE3-4D2F-8026-C11CBC35C609/Page/p102> ; data: {
    address = "http://stackoverflow.com";
    name = Stackoverflow;
    oldMD5 = cd32dbfb6fc3f7cca09f45ee811cab0;
    updated = 0;
})
```

So, the updated value is lost during the save. Still, the oldMD5 value works perfectly. Anyone got an idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Any chance you have the update key set to be transient?  That's the only thing I can think of right now.

Comment: Does the `update` attribute have a default value of 0?

Comment: Yes it does (actually set to NO, but i guess that's the same thing?)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you've registered the background thread to receive notifications of its own changes. That is pointless. You need to register the foreground context to receive notifications for changes to the background context because you need to merge the two context.

Secondly, I suspect that your save on the background context is failing but since you don't trap the error return you can't see.  Exceptions work differently in Objective-C/Apple-API than they do in Java, C++ or C#. In objective-C, exceptions are for unanticipated issues. Since a failed save is always an anticipated possibility, the save operation will not generate an exception if it occurs but will simply report the error.

Trap and log the error and it will tell you why the save failed.

Comment: Well, I just tried to check the error, and it's null. I added the code and output to the original question above. I don't get what you are trying to say with the notification registerations, i just used the code from [here](http://www.duckrowing.com/2010/03/11/using-core-data-on-multiple-threads/)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, it must have been XCode bug or something. Basically I made a new attribute with same options and changed the code to use it instead of updated attribute. Everything works now. Although the Transient option of updated was not checked, I think it still was transient, XCode just didn't change it.